# php remove slashes from date

Tags: php, regex

I have a function called convert which take in date (20140107) and replace the 4,2,2 position with a slash / (2014/01/07)for the date to be readable on the screen I will like to also remove the slashes before I sending it to the database
In summary, this is what I am trying to do take a date of this form 2014/01/07 and convert it to 20140107

below is the convert function

```
function convert($date) 
{
  $numbers_only = preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $date);
  return preg_replace("/^1?(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/", "$1/$2/$3", $numbers_only);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use   `str_replace`

```
function convert($date) 
{
  str_replace("/", "", $date);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to use a Datetime object as a middle man for this.

Create from format would allow you to create a Datetime without using string manipulation

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

You can then use the format function to output it in the way that you prefer.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Along the lines of...

```
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $date);
echo $dateObj->format('Ymd');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace). Much simpler:

```
echo str_replace('/', '', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in PHP function [`str_replace()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). So just call

```
return str_replace('/', null, $numbers_only);
```

Instead of

```
return preg_replace("/^1?(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/", "$1/$2/$3", $numbers_only);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalDate = "2014/01/07";
$newDate = date("Ymd", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate;
```